# How to format my time display to show daylight savings label?

Tags: javascript, time, ecmascript-6, timezone, momentjs

my time is showing like this

`moment(date).tz(TimeZone).format('h:mm a z')`

`1:02 p.m. EST`

what I would like it for it to say

`1:02 p.m. EDT`

how can i change it to daylight savings time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't do that in moment

```
jun.tz('America/New_York').format('ha z'); // 8am EDT
dec.tz('America/New_York').format('ha z'); // 7am EST
```

in the winter its always est i think

Answer (score 1):

Whenever it comes to issues such as date or time, if you want to get a tailored result it helps to refactor code to a sort of date class.  Fortunately, [dateJS](https://code.google.com/archive/p/datejs/wikis/APIDocumentation.wiki) a javascript library that deals with date and time could help you out.

In reference to displaying daylight savings time, this example gives you what you want.

getTimezoneAbbreviation

```
Date.getTimezoneAbbreviation ( Number timezoneOffset, Boolean isDayLightSavingsTime ) : String

Returns a culture-specific timezone abbreviation based on a given offset and a boolean indicating whether daylight savings time is in effect.

Parameters
{Number timezoneOffset} The year.
{Boolean isDayLightSavingsTime} Whether the date instance is observing Daylight Saving Time (Summer Time)
Return Value
{String} The timezone abbreviation

Example
var today = Date.today(); Date.getTimezoneAbbreviation(today.getTimezoneOffset, today.isDayLightSavingsTime()); // "UTC", "GMT", "EST", "PDT", etc.
```